# using a static Qt in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, static, qt-creator

I created a static Qt environment using this tutorial:
https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW

Then I copied the resulting folder (from a virtual machine) to "D:\QtSDK_Static1"

Now when I try to add the "D:\QtSDK_Static1\5.5.1\bin\qmake.exe" to Qt versions I get the following error:

> QT version is not properly installed, please run make install

I also added the folder "D:\QtSDK_Static1\5.5.1\bin" to the path variable.

How can I get Qt Creator to use the static Qt-Libs?

Comment: No wonder that you install a program on one machine, copied folder to another and it doesn't work? Why not build static Qt on a machine where you will use it?

Comment: because the build is done using a Windows PowerShell script and i don't have sufficient rights to run the script on the machine where i want to use it. (even if I run the script as administrator).

Answer (score 1):

Qt installations can not be moved from their initial path. Set up your VM so that Qt will be built in the same path as in the target system.

> the build is done using a Windows PowerShell script

Why? It doesn't have to be :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the solution:

simply had to add a file called

> qt.conf

in the qmake.exe folder (in my case D:\QtSDK_Static1\5.5.1\bin) with the following content:

```
[Paths]
Prefix = D:/QtSDK_Static1/5.5.1/
Translations = translations
```

Comment: This worked for me fixing a similar issue. Worth noting that the path separators do need to be '/', not '\'. '\\' might work.